# Add Notification to Magento 2.3 Customer Registration About Shipping Restriction to California

Tags: magento2.3, php, register, registration

I want to add a notification that appears on the registration page - only when California is selected as a state. Otherwise it will not display. I am unsure of the parameters. I am using Magento 2.3

The current code on the registration.phtml is the following:

```
<div class="field region required">
                <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                        <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select a region, state or province.')) ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region')) ?>" style="display:none;">

                </div>
            </div>
```

and my PHP is this, which isn't working:

```
<?php if ($region_id == '12') {echo '<div class="no-cali">Please note: We do not ship to California.</div>';} else { echo '';} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display dynamic content like that You should use JS.
I mean, add for example hidden div like this

```
<div class="no-cali hidden">Please note: We do not ship to California.</div>
```

then using js / jq, add observer to this select `region_id` on change value.
Then check if value is specific one and change visibility. In that case remove or add `hidden` class.

Here You can check how to do that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416767/get-selected-value-text-from-select-on-change/47495878